# Docker daemon out of memory but memory available on host

Tags: docker

I have been looking here and elsewhere on Internet and didn't find answer to my problem.

Here is the situation.

My system is not running out of memory:

```
  System information as of Sat May 23 12:06:56 CEST 2020

  System load:  0.02               Users logged in:                0
  Usage of /:   72.8% of 38.71GB   IP address for ens3:            92.222.89.93
  Memory usage: 12%                IP address for docker_gwbridge: 172.18.0.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for docker0:         172.17.0.1
  Processes:    126
```

My docker daemon does not show any problem:

```
top - 12:14:46 up 2 days, 22:11,  1 user,  load average: 37.87, 21.54, 26.91
Tasks: 187 total,   2 running, 140 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us, 92.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  6.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3941032 total,   118616 free,  3720504 used,   101912 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.    14676 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                         
   34 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 71.6  0.0  28:08.90 kswapd0                                                         
11405 root      20   0  117504   3920      0 S  0.9  0.1   0:00.32 caddy                                                           
 1005 root      20   0  934736  61288      0 S  0.7  1.6  19:09.86 dockerd
```

But I get an `out of memory` error when I invoke docker commands:

```
# docker ps
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x55d00d234abc, 0x16)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x74 fp=0x7ffc081913c0 sp=0x7ffc08191390 pc=0x55d00bc58574
runtime.sysMap(0xc000000000, 0x4000000, 0x55d00f1ddf98)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:170 +0xc9 fp=0x7ffc08191400 sp=0x7ffc081913c0 pc=0x55d00bc43889
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x55d00f1c4a80, 0x2000, 0x55d00f1c4a90, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:633 +0x1cf fp=0x7ffc081914a8 sp=0x7ffc08191400 pc=0x55d00bc3669f
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x55d00f1c4a80, 0x1, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1222 +0x44 fp=0x7ffc08191500 sp=0x7ffc081914a8 pc=0x55d00bc50c94
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x55d00f1c4a80, 0x1, 0x55d00f1ddfa8, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1150 +0x381 fp=0x7ffc08191538 sp=0x7ffc08191500 pc=0x55d00bc50b81
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x55d00f1c4a80, 0x1, 0x2a, 0x6e43a318)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:977 +0xc6 fp=0x7ffc08191588 sp=0x7ffc08191538 pc=0x55d00bc501d6
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1048 +0x4e fp=0x7ffc081915c0 sp=0x7ffc08191588 pc=0x55d00bc812fe
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x55d00f1c4a80, 0x1, 0x55d00b01002a, 0x7ffc08191660)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:1047 +0x8c fp=0x7ffc08191610 sp=0x7ffc081915c0 pc=0x55d00bc504ac
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0x55d00f1c5880, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:256 +0x97 fp=0x7ffc08191658 sp=0x7ffc08191610 pc=0x55d00bc43307
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x55d00f1c5880, 0x7ff733676000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:106 +0x301 fp=0x7ffc081916b8 sp=0x7ffc08191658 pc=0x55d00bc42e11
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x7ff733676008, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:135 +0x88 fp=0x7ffc081916d8 sp=0x7ffc081916b8 pc=0x55d00bc428a8
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x7ff733676008, 0x55d00f1ba92a, 0x7ff733676008, 0x7ff733676000, 0x8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:786 +0x8a fp=0x7ffc08191710 sp=0x7ffc081916d8 pc=0x55d00bc36eda
runtime.mallocgc(0x180, 0x55d00df28480, 0x1, 0x55d00f1de000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:939 +0x780 fp=0x7ffc081917b0 sp=0x7ffc08191710 pc=0x55d00bc37810
runtime.newobject(0x55d00df28480, 0x4000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1068 +0x3a fp=0x7ffc081917e0 sp=0x7ffc081917b0 pc=0x55d00bc37c1a
runtime.malg(0x22b1800008000, 0x55d00f1c70f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:3220 +0x33 fp=0x7ffc08191820 sp=0x7ffc081917e0 pc=0x55d00bc61a23
runtime.mpreinit(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:311
runtime.mcommoninit(0x55d00f1bed40)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:618 +0xc6 fp=0x7ffc08191858 sp=0x7ffc08191820 pc=0x55d00bc5b396
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:540 +0x78 fp=0x7ffc081918b0 sp=0x7ffc08191858 pc=0x55d00bc5b028
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ffc081919b8, 0x2, 0x7ffc081919b8, 0x0, 0x7ff732ca9b97, 0x2, 0x7ffc081919b8, 0x200008000, 0x55d00bc83370, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:195 +0x11e fp=0x7ffc081918b8 sp=0x7ffc081918b0 pc=0x55d00bc8349e
```

Any suggestion is welcome although I am not sure to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Have you set a limit to how much memory a container can use?  https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: Which docker version are you using?

Comment: @John Manko: no, what I understand is that would prevent containers to use all system memory, which is not my problem. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Raj Srujan Jalem: At the moment I have "Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c" on "Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-101-generic x86_64)".

Answer (score 0):

After I set a memory limit on one of my container as advised by @John Manko the problem didn't arise anymore. It seems that this fixed my problem.